# mysqldump without locking table and data integrity

Tags: innodb, mysql

I want to mysqldump a huge innodb database without locking table using (--single-transaction --quick) while new records are getting inserted into the database.  the mysqldump process will last a long time and the insertion will finish soon.
My question is:
would mysqldump dump the all the records including the newly inserted ones that were inserted after the start of mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

No, InnoDB will use its built-in transaction semantics to present the table's contents at the instant you started fetching it. Rows that come into the table after you started fetching it are not included.

If your table is busy, things may slow down significantly while mysqldump is running.